# android pending intent notification problem

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I have a alarm thing going on in my app and it launches a notification that then when pressed launched an activity.
The problem is that when I create more than one alarm then the activity launched from the notification gets the same extras as the first one. I think the problem is either with the intent i put in the pending intent or in the pending intent itself. I think I might need to put a flag on one of these but I dont know which one.

```
Intent showIntent =new Intent(context, notificationreceiver.class);
    showIntent.putExtra("details", alarmname);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        showIntent, 0); 

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "The event is imminent",
            alarmname, contentIntent);
```

And the receiver of the notification

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String eventname = b.getString("details");
    details.setText(eventname);
```

The "details" extra is the same to every the next time a notification happens instead of having the different value.
Until I set the intents I am sure that the correct value goes to the "details" so its a problem of getting the first intent everytime i press any notification.
How can I make it to launch the correct intents?
Hope I was as clear as i could
Thanks!

Comment: What I did is since I am using a unique notificationId to keep track of the statuses (status bar notification), i use the same variable to pass into my PendingIntent thus making it unique.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> The problem is that when I create more
>   than one alarm then the activity
>   launched from the notification gets
>   the same extras as the first one.

Correct.

> How can I make it to launch the
>   correct intents?

That depends on whether you have two alarms that will be registered at once, or not.

If not, you can [use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` or one of the other `PendingIntent` flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982452/putting-data-in-the-sms-sent-intent) to have your second `PendingIntent` use the newer extras.

If, however, you will have two alarms registered at once, with different `Intent` extras, you will need to make the two `Intents` be more materially different, such that [`filterEquals()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) returns `false` when comparing the two. For example, you could call `setData()` or `setAction()` and provide different values for each `Intent`.

Comment: Man thanks alot for the help. Because there is the possibility to have alarms going of together and having more than one notification on the notification bar I used the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag for the pending intent.
But the real deal was as you said to setAction on the intent with the alarm name and now it could know which intents are different and what the same.
Thanks again!

Comment: setAction worked for me too. I just wonder why the official SDK doesn't mention it.

Comment: setAction works, thanks a TON. Using setAction helped me differentiate all the pendingIntents, just awesome!

Comment: using setAction to set different Action for each content Intent was key for me. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: You can also use a different request code when creating pending intents, with a hash, that's quite convenient, and maybe cleaner than using setData

Comment: thanks alot :),i make app that give more than one notification at different time and make different action to each notification so faced this problem when put extra data but it solved just by using  Intent intent1=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Splash.class);
        intent1.putExtra("iqama_ID",6);:PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), notification_id,
                intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: @CommonsWare I have set up my pendingIntents with unique requestCodes, using an int counter.  I am trying to cancel a pendingIntent in Activity A from Activity B here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161676/android-cancel-alarm-and-pendingintent-in-different-activity  Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 122):

The way I solved that problem was by assigning a unique **requestCode** when you get the PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, showIntent, 0);
```

By doing so you are registering with the system different/unique intent instances.
**Tip:** A good way of making the requestCode unique would be by passing to it the current system time.

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: requestCode is indeed not used by anything as of yet, but it does make the intents unique which stops them being overwritten! Excellent work u-ramos!

Comment: Even if `TaskStackBuilder` is being used, we have a method there `getPendingIntent(int requestCode, int flags)` .Here this requestID can be passed to.

Comment: Be careful, currentTimeMillis is type long, so if you cast to int, it will be truncated.
I don't know how probable is and if it matters, but it could be repeated.
In that case you can use a static incremented value

Comment: What if you want later to cancel the `PendingIntent`? You should store the requestCode for each `PendingIntent`?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the solution provided by U-ramos and this worked for me

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, showIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my app and just generated a random number to over come overriding notifications intent:

```
int random= new Random().nextInt();
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
      stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
              random,
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
      );
```

Answer (score -1):

**another solution:**

use the **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

this worked for me

Comment: This doesn't work. It replaces the old parameters and replaces with new ones