# Notification using pending intent

Tags: android

I am uploading the photos asynchronously from the device. As I am uploading asynchronously, I want to notify user when the asynchronous upload has been completed. I am able to upload the photos asynchronously, but i am not able to notify the user. 
How this can be achieved using pending intents and broadcast receivers ?

Answer (score 0):

In `PendingIntent` you can use different request code to notify the user when each picture is uploaded, else use same request code for notifying when the picture uploading is completed.

refer this link :[Pending Intent Notification Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009059/android-pending-intent-notification-problem)

Hope it will be useful...