# Detect Email Sent or Not in onActivity Result

Tags: android, email

I want to detect whether person has send the email or pressed back button or discarded it, in my onActivityResult Method. How can I do the same.

I am doing it like this

```
String[] reciepients = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
        Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,reciepients);
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailMessage);
        email.setType("text/plain");
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        Intent intent =  Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose Email Client");
        //context.start(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose Email.."));
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, FinalVariables.SEND_EMAIL);
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {


        case FinalVariables.SEND_EMAIL:
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                showToast("Cancelled");
            }
            else if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
                showToast("Success");
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

But this way it always gives me cancelled, as Email client never sets the RESULT as RESULT_OK.

**So how can I fulfill my requirement. Please suggest.**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778048/how-can-we-use-startactivityforresult-for-email-intent)

- You can't, this is not part of the API. It returns once you have
  pressed send button even if it is not sent

Not sure but You are getting the for RESULT_CANCELED because it looks it is default it user not set Result ok then it consider RESULT_CANCELED and email activity never sets result RESULT_OK so it takes as RESULT_CANCELED .

- You can check it by cheeking Intent data coming back will always null
  either mail send or discard.

Comment: elaborate the 2nd case ? how can I check with intent data ?

Comment: Intent data always returns `null` in both cases. You can't check intent data.

Answer (score 7):

After reading tones of staff on this issue I understood that there is no way to know exactly if the user pressed "Send" or just canceled.

But there is a way to find out at least if the user has opened any mail client application or pressed back from the "Complete action using" dialog. (In my case I just wanted to finish activity if the user opened mail client and do nothing if the user pressed back from the dialog). The trick is very simple.

As the dialog is a floating window, when it is being shown over the activity, only the **onPause()** method is being called in activity, but when the user chose a mail client and it is being opened the **onStop()** method of activity is also being called. So you can start ACTION_SEND with **startActivityForResult()** :

```
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_SEND);
```

and also have a boolean flag that you will change in **onPause()** and **onStop()**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...

private boolean mailClientOpened = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mailClientOpened = false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mailClientOpened = true;
}
```

and in your **onActivityResult()** you can check the **requestCode** and the boolean **mailClientOpened** to know if the client was opened or user canceled the dialog:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CODE_SEND && mailClientOpened){
    finish(); // Or do something else that you need to do when you know that user at least opened the mail client app
        }
    }
```

P.S. I know that this is not an exact answer to the question but I hope this can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED" + serialnum; // Unique ACTION every time
Intent delivered = new Intent(context, MessageStatusReceiver.class);
delivered.setAction(DELIVERED ); // Set action to ensure unique PendingIntent
delivered.putExtra("MsgNum", serialnum);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
Integer.parseInt(serialnum), delivered,
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

**Reference:** [Differentiating delivery reports of two separate SMS's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781383/differentiating-delivery-reports-of-two-seperate-smss)

Comment: to get the delivery report of your sent mails

Comment: that is mentioned in the attached link, did you referred?

Comment: The question was about email not SMS