# Resultcode is not proper when sending email in android

Tags: android, email

I want to show a Toast on sending the email successfully, I am sending an Email with the following code-

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {sToEmail});   
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,emailHeader); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailText);   
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"), REQUEST_CODE);
```

In onActivity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Sent...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
}
```

Problem is that I am getting result code 0 every time when I am sending, cancelling, discarding the mail.
Result Code is not proper.

Please reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102578/detect-email-sent-or-not-in-onactivity-result?answertab=votes#tab-top